# PlayFramework how can I get correct file path on upload

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have play framework version 2.46 and I am uploading files to my amazon S3 account, however I keep getting the path to the tmp file. Here is my code

```
  def upload = Action (parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request =>
    request.body.file("file").map { file =>


      val credentials: AWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("Key", "Secret-key")
      val s3client: AmazonS3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials)
      val bucketName: String = "myfolder"

     val myfile:File= new File(file.filename)

      s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName,file.filename,new File(myfile.getAbsolutePath)))
        Ok("File uploaded")
      }.getOrElse {
      Redirect(routes.Application.index).flashing(
        "error" -> "Missing file")
    }
  }
```

The part that is giving me issues is the **myfile.getAbsolutePath** part it is returning an error file not found. I know exactly why but do not know how to fix it for instance if I have a file at *C:\mypictures\Users\bus.jp*g then **myfile.getAbsolutePath** would turn it to *C:\mypictures\Calc\bus.jpg* . My PlayFramework application is named Calc and offcourse that picture does not exist in that location.

- Works: new File("C:\mypictures\Users\bus.jpg") = C:\mypictures\Users\bus.jpg
- Does not work new File(myfile.getAbsolutePath)= C:\mypictures\Calc\bus.jpg

How can I fix this so that the correct file location gets uploaded ? I been stuck at this for a few hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're looking for the web app to pull the file from that location on your computer, instead of it receiving the file in the HTTP request.

`val myfile:File= new File(file.filename)` won't work, because you're taking the name (not the path) of the uploaded file, and creating a `File` with that name and the current working directory - this is then reflected when you use it to get the absolute directory.

It also isn't needed because you already have a `TemporaryFile`.  From the [documentation](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaFileUpload):

```
def upload = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
  request.body.file("picture").map { picture =>
    import java.io.File
    val filename = picture.filename
    val contentType = picture.contentType
    picture.ref.moveTo(new File(s"/tmp/picture/$filename"))
    Ok("File uploaded")
  }.getOrElse {
    Redirect(routes.Application.index).flashing(
      "error" -> "Missing file")
  }
}
```

Accordingly, you can use that temporary file to give you everything you need.  Your code then becomes

```
def upload = Action (parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request =>
  request.body.file("file").map { file =>
    val credentials: AWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("Key", "Secret-key")
    val s3client: AmazonS3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials)
    val bucketName: String = "myfolder"

    s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName,
                                            file.filename,
                                            file.ref.file))
      Ok("File uploaded")
    }.getOrElse {
      Redirect(routes.Application.index).flashing(
        "error" -> "Missing file")
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot that solved my issue !! appreciate it.